# Find all surjective functions $f(x+f(y))+f(y+f(x))=f(f(2x)+2y)$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

Find all surjective functions: $f:R_0^+→R_0^+$ such that:
$$f(x+f(y))+f(y+f(x))=f(f(2x)+2y)$$

Note that $0$ is not in the domain and codomain.

This is what i found:
$2f(x+f(x))=f(f(2x)+2x)$
And for some $a\in{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $f(a)=1$ :
$f(x+1)+f(a+f(x))=f(f(2x)+2a)$ is that good? I don't know how to continue.
Also: i noticed that $f(x)=x$ satisfy the conditions.

Comment: Here is the solution: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2313598p18404101

Comment: I see that you are on the same type of functional equation as in your previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4240939) with a little more work on it. As Aqua has asked, could you tell us the source of your functional equations problems.

Comment: Related: [Finding all surjective functions satisfying $ f \big( f ( a ) + b \big) + f \big( f ( b ) + a ) = f \big( 2 a + f ( 2 b ) \big) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2343011/229831)

Comment: I found the link above using Approach0. See [this](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f%5Cleft(x%2Bf%5Cleft(y%5Cright)%5Cright)%2Bf%5Cleft(y%2Bf%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%5Cright)%3Df%5Cleft(f%5Cleft(2x%5Cright)%2B2y%5Cright)%24&p=1). I suggest you search what you want before asking, so that if there is a similar post here or on AOPS, you don't post a duplicate.

Comment: @Beginner Please, as asked some hours ago, could you cite the source of your functional equations problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea:

> Since swapping $x$ and $y$ we get the same expression on LHS we see that $$f(f(2x)+2y)= f(f(2y)+2x)$$ so, if we prove $f$ is injective we get $$f(2x)-2x= f(2y)-2y$$ which implies $f(x)= x$ for all $x$.

> So we are left to prove $f$ is injective...